# How to sum an arbitrary polynomial series in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, sum, series, polynomials

Given:

```
y=[y(1),y(2),...,y(n)]
```

Where `n` is input by the user, and:

```
x=[x(1),x(2),...,x(n)]

a=[a0,a1,...,am]=[a(1),a(2),...,a(m+1)]
```

Where `m` is also input by the user, then I need to compute:

```
y(p) = a0*x(p)^0 + a1*x(p)^1 + a2*x(p)^2 + ... + am*x(p)^m

y(p) = a(1)*x(p)^0 + a(2)*x(p)^1 + a(3)*x(p)^2 + ... + a(m+1)*x(p)^m.
```

i.e. Each element of `y` is a polynomial in `m`, `y=a0+a1x+a2x^2+...+amx^m`, using the `p`<sup>th</sup> `x` value for the `p`<sup>th</sup> `y` value.

In summation notation:

```
y(p) = **sum** (from q=0 to m) **[a(q+1)*x(p)^q]**
```

I'm not sure how to sum this series in MATLAB. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

I've attempted to evaluate each value of `y(p)` by the following, for example, `y(2)`:

```
syms q a x  
f=a(q+1)*x(2)^q
y(2) = symsum(f, q, 0, m)
```

However, this returns the error `Invalid indexing or function definition`.

Comment: Where exactly are you having difficulty in summing this series? Have you attempted to code this? If so, where is it failing? Can you give us a [mcve]?

Comment: I've edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `x` defined as an `N`-element row vector of values, and `a` defined as an `M`-element row vector of polynomial coefficients, then you can use the function [`polyval`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyval.html) to calculate your `y` values for a subset of `m+1` polynomial terms and `n` values of `x`:

```
y = polyval(flip(a(1:(m+1)), 2), x(1:n));
```

Note that `polyval` expects the polynomial coefficients ordered from highest power to lowest power, so the order of the vector `a(1:(m+1))` has to be flipped using [`flip`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flip.html).

Answer (score 0):

> Code is completely descriptive, in this code `meshgrid` function plays a core role, if code is not so descriptive , then I recommend to learn basics in matlab(What are matrices and how to deal with them in matlab)

```
% Inputs , for example x=[1,2,3,..,10] and a=[5,6,7,8]

x=1:10
a=[5,6,7,8]

% m <= length(a)

m=3

% temporary matrices

[tx,ta] = meshgrid(x,a)
[~,tm]=meshgrid(x,0:m)
t=ta(1:m+1,:).*tx(1:m+1,:).^tm(1:m+1,:)

% y is your result and has equal elemnts to x matrix

y=sum(t,1)

% some outputs

y(2)
y(3)
```

aslo, error mentioned in Question has a reason which is described in [https://stackoverflow.com/a/47782904/6478645]