# symsum function error - invalid indexing or function definition?

Tags: matlab, sum, series

I'm attempting to sum the following using the symsum function in MATLAB:

**sum (from q=0 to 5) [a(q+1)*x(2)^q]**

where a=[a0, a1, ..., a5], x=[x(1), x(2), ...] where x(1), x(2), ... are scalars.

The sum is a0 + a1x(2)+a2x(2)^2 +...+a5x(2)^5.

I've used the following code:

```
syms q a x  
f=a(q+1)*x(2)^q
symsum(f, q, 0, 5)
```

where x(2)= -4.9.

However, the above code returns "Invalid indexing or function definition".

Using f=x(2)^q does not result in the error, however, using f=a(q+1) does return the error. Therefore the problem lies within the a(q+1) term.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: does `x(2)` exist?

Comment: Yes, x=[-5:0.1:5], so x(2)= -4.9.

Comment: have you tried this: `syms q a  
f=a(q+1)*(-4.9)^q
symsum(f, q, 0, 5) `

Comment: Unfortunately, that's still returning the same error. I've tried f=a(q+1) on it's own, and this returns the same error. However f=(-4.9)^q does not return the error - therefore the problem lies in the a(q+1) term, if this is any help

Comment: ah, I see, there is no `a(6)` when q = 5...

Comment: I think a0=a(1) and so a5=a(6)

Comment: you are right, I am not very sure, but maybe a is not `syms`, just a pointer

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter `a` is matrix of symbolics or non-symbolics.

Every call to a matrix need an index(a number, real number like 1,2,3,4,...)
When `q` is a symbolic it means q really doesn't equal to any number, so `a(q)`
has no meaning because `q` has no equality to any number. So programs make error and stops before going more.

```
>>a=0:5;
>> a(1)

ans =

     0
>>a(q) % ?-->do you know the real value of `q` right now? NO,nobody knows!
    MAKES ERROR
```